# run function wordpress code update sql - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

please help me
**How can I run this code in WordPress?**

```
    function update_19_0()
{
    $this->alterTables( array(
        'bookly_staff' => array(
            **'ALTER TABLE `%s` ADD COLUMN `zoom_personal` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0',
            'ALTER TABLE `%s` ADD COLUMN `zoom_jwt_api_key` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL',
            'ALTER TABLE `%s` ADD COLUMN `zoom_jwt_api_secret` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL',**
        ),
        'bookly_customers' => array(
            'ALTER TABLE `%s` ADD COLUMN `stripe_account` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL AFTER `info_fields`',
        ),
    ) );
}
```

please run php in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

See below an example using the dbDelta function.

This example does not provide the exact function for your code. However, it would give you the reference to run SQL statements on WordPress.

class Bookly_Activator {

```
static $table_name = 'bookly_staff';
static $db_version = '0.1';
static $db_option = 'bookly_staff_db_version';

/**
 * Short Description. (use period)
 *
 * Long Description.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public static function activate() {

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . self::$table_name;

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name(
```

`id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`key` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) $charset_collate;";

```
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );

    add_option( self::$db_option, self::$db_version );

}
```

}

Reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/

Regards.
Eduardo Estevez.